# Use Terraform v0.12 to add an aws_s3_bucket_policy to a list of buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I would like to create a policy template and apply it to a list of buckets but I am having a problem with getting the current bucket's name into the policy. Terraform returns the error

```
"Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource"
```

twice. Plan is working fine, the output for the policy looks good etc.

```
variable "s3_bucket_list" 
  { 
    type        = list(string)
    description = "List of buckets to secure"
    default     = ["bucket1","bucket2"]   
   }
```

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "qpp-secure-bucket" {
  count  = length(var.s3_bucket_list)
  bucket = var.s3_bucket_list[count.index]
  }

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "minimum_s3_bucket_policy" {
  count  = length(var.s3_bucket_list)
  bucket = var.s3_bucket_list[count.index]

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnencryptedCommunication",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_list[count.index]}/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct policy is

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "secure-bucket" {
  count  = length(var.s3_bucket_list)
  bucket = var.s3_bucket_list[count.index]

  policy = <<POLICY {   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnencryptedCommunication",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_list[count.index]}",
         "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_list[count.index]}/*"      
        ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }   ] } POLICY

}
```